# How can I build a CoreData in Swift Playground for iPad?

Tags: swift, core-data, swift-playground

I tried to use the new iPad Swift Playground and I want to use CoreDate, but there is no CoreData tools like those in Xcode, the only thing I can do in this Playground is:

```
import CoreData
```

so is there a way to use CoreData?

Comment: The only thing you need from Xcode is the .xcdatamodel file, which I think you can just import into Playgrounds as a resource file. Then you will just create the core data stack as normal. I'm not sure about if you are allowed to _write_ files on the iPad Playgrounds though. That said, why on earth do you need CoreData?

Comment: @sweeper the new Swift playgrounds on iPad allows you to create and upload full apps. So I imagine it’s for that??

Comment: @Fogmeister Oh really? You can do that now? I haven't used the app since the Swift 3 days lol.

Comment: You can do Core Data in code, with no data model file. I wrote a blog post on it here: https://www.atomicbird.com/blog/core-data-code-only/

Comment: @Sweeper no, app does not allow select xcdatamodel or xcdatamodeld (it is a folder) on iPad